# How to broadcast image with socket.io in Golang?

Tags: go, socket.io

I want to use socket.io to broadcast images in Golang(Server side). I already know how to do it in Node.js, but I have no idea with Golang. Codes are below:

Node.js(worked):

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
   io.on('connection', function(socket){
       fs.readFile(imagepath, (err, buf)=>{
       socket.broadcast.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: 
       buf.toString('base64') });
   }
```

Go(not worked):

```
type data struct {
    image  bool
    buffer string
}
server, _ := socketio.NewServer(nil)    
server.On("connection", func(socket socketio.Socket) {
                f, _ := os.Open(imagepath)
                reader := bufio.NewReader(f)
                content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
                encoded := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(content)
                socket.Emit("image", data{true, encoded})
        })
```

client side(worked with Server side using Node.js):

```
var img = document.getElementById('img')
var socket = io();
socket.on('image', function(info) {
if(info.image)
{ img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + info.buffer;}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. 

The declare of data struct in GO should be:

```
type data struct {
Image  bool   `json:"image"`
Buffer string `json:"buffer"`}
```

Then it works!